# During React 'Compilation', do props get optimized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I know React dosen't nesscary go through a compilation, but there is some sort of minification process which occurs on production builds.

My application has components that use a lot of props. I've been in the habbit of trying to make a lot of features configruable (via props) in all my components. Such as a list might have a number of items variable, or I might have a bool to turn on/off some styling.

My question is, are there any performance pitfalls of doing this? For example, if I have a list component:

```
export default class List extends React.Component {

}
List.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.number
}

List.defaultProps = {
  children: 10
}
```

And I never actually change the children prop from its default value of 10, will that hurt my performance as I always reference 'this.props.children'. Should I just be using a const variable instead?

I guess my question relates to other lanaguages, as often a compiler will detect if a variable is never changed and optimize its usage. Currious if something similar happens here.

(I know I am likely overoptimizing, just curious how this all works)

Comment: A constant will probably be faster overall, however that really depends on how it is used, and whatsoever the difference will be very small. I'd rather optimize for readability and YAGNI.

Comment: gotcha. interesting that there is a performance difference though, maybe i could add a preprocessor to detect these and set them to constants